# Jackson excluding type information for containeirs (List, Map, Collection) during serialization

Tags: java, json, jackson

In **Jackson** I want to include type-information for every custom objects. To accomplish this without annotation, I am using

```
OBJECT_MAPPER.enableDefaultTypingAsProperty(DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL, "@Ketan");
```

It is working but it is also including type-information for `List`, `Map`, `Collection` like container itself.

Let me give you a standard example of `Animal`, `Dog`, `Cat` and `Zoo` hierarchy.

```
class Zoo {

    List<Cat> cats;
    Dog dog;

    public Dog getDog() {
       return dog;
    }

    public void setDog(Dog dog) {
       this.dog = dog;
    }

    public List<Cat> getCats() {
       return cats;
    }

    public void setCats(List<Cat> cats) {
       this.cats = cats;
    }

}
```

Here, I have two custom objects, `Cat` and `Dog`. I just want to include type information for only those, but it is including for container – `List` in my case – as well.

Please see below the JSON string I got by serialization.

```
{
    "@Ketan": "com.csam.wsc.enabling.core.codec.json.test.Zoo1",
    "cats": [
        // This line contains the issue //
        "java.util.ArrayList",
        [
            {
                "@Ketan": "com.csam.wsc.enabling.core.codec.json.test.Cat",
                "name": "animalName",
                "likesCream": true,
                "lives": 10
            },
            {
                "@Ketan": "com.csam.wsc.enabling.core.codec.json.test.Cat",
                "name": "animalName",
                "likesCream": true,
                "lives": 10
            }
        ]
    ],
    "dog": {
        "@Ketan": "com.csam.wsc.enabling.core.codec.json.test.Dog",
        "name": "animalName",
        "barkVolume": 0.0
    }
}
```

Everything is fine to me except what I have highlighted – `java.util.ArrayList` in the JSON string. I do not want such a container type information.

Is there any easy support at above API level itself to achieve this without overriding `TypeResolverBuilder` or any customization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unless you declare your Collections to be final types.

Comment: ok..thanks again for prompt reply.So what is the easiest way to achieve exact above behavior?

Comment: You can override behavior wrt type inclusion by offering custom `StdTypeResolverBuilder` (and overriding its `useForType` method); and then calling `ObjectMapper.setDefaultTyping(myTRB)`. Class `useForType` (inner sub-class of `ObjectMapper`) shows how default behavior works.

Comment: A huge thanks....Finally used this approach and it has fulfilled all my requirements...

Comment: Ok good. It is pretty much hidden in there (wasn't thought to be commonly needed extension point), but really useful when you need it. Should probably blog about that one.

Comment: Yes , I am agree with you. I would like to blog this one

Answer (score 7):

If you extend the class `ObjectMapper.DefaultTypeResolverBuilder`, it becomes quite easy though:

```
OBJECT_MAPPER.setDefaultTyping(new ObjectMapper.DefaultTypeResolverBuilder(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL) {
    {
        init(JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, null);
        inclusion(JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY);
        typeProperty("@Ketan");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean useForType(JavaType t) {
        return !t.isContainerType() && super.useForType(t);
    }
});
```