# Jackson serialize class name as property for all objects

Tags: java, json, spring, serialization, jackson

I'd like the class name of all POJOs Jackson serializes to JSON objects to be included as a property of the respective object. Ideally, this should be achieved through some general setting of the ObjectMapper or similar.

Serialization example:

```java
public class MyClass {
  private String someField;
  private MyOtherClass anotherField;
}
```

to

```
{
  "$type": "MyClass",
  "someField": "abc",
  "anotherField": {
    "$type": "MyOtherClass",
    ...
  }
}
```

I know this could also be done by annotating all the respective classes with something like

```java
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "$type")
```

But I'd like to avoid that.

I've also tried

```java
objectMapper.enableDefaultTypingAsProperty(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.JAVA_LANG_OBJECT, "$type")
```

which didn't seem to work.

Is there such a general setting available?

---

**EDIT:**
Thanks to AZWN's hints I actually got what I was looking for by customizing and constructing a `TypeResolverBuilder` with `DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL`.

```java
StdTypeResolverBuilder typer = new ObjectMapper.DefaultTypeResolverBuilder(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL) {
    @Override
    public boolean useForType(JavaType t) {
        return !(t.isCollectionLikeType() || t.isMapLikeType()) && super.useForType(t);
    }
}
        .init(JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, null)
        .inclusion(JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY)
        .typeProperty("$type");

objectMapper.setDefaultTyping(typer);
```

Comment: The general setting **is** `enableDefaultTypingAsProperty`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL` instead of `ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.JAVA_LANG_OBJECT`, since the latter one only includes type properties when the *field type* of a class is `Object` at *compile time*.

For more info, see [the docs](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization). Also, be aware of the security issues they mention.

Comment: Thank you! So it was just the DefaultTyping value. This already brought me a lot further. Unfortunately, now lists also include their class name as the first attribute when serialized, e.g. `["ArrayList", ...]`.
I suppose there's no way to exclude them from this mechanism?

Comment: Not by default unfortunately. You could implement a custom `TypeResolverBuilder`, and use `ObjectMapper.setDefaultTyping`, but that is somewhat more difficult. See for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41768995/5660613

Comment: Right! That actually got me exactly what I wanted. Thanks again! I'll update my question to show the solution I ended up with.